# Finding answers with specific links

Tags: support, search, broken-link

I have (probably) a large number of posts on SO with links to my specific domain (to provide expanded information beyond what's put in the answers).

If I were to switch to a different domain (say, moving from `pax.com` to `pax.org`), it would be useful to get a list of those posts so as to go and modify them, so as to avoid broken links.

Yet, when I search for the domain name on SO, no hits are returned. What's the best way to get a list of posts containing links to (for example) `pax.com`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `url` operator should help. e.g. [`url:wikipedia.org`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Awikipedia.org).

Comment: Thanks, Adam, that worked fine.